# What is the use of open system call in *nix

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io

What is `open()`? What does this do?

```
if (open("/dev/null", O_RDWR) < 0) {
  die("error=open: %m");
}
```

Comment: The `%m` part of the format string in the call to `die()` is intriguing.  It isn't a standard `printf()` format letter, and no value is passed to `die()` for it.  Presumably, it will contain the string from `strerror(errno)`.  The other intriguing thing is that the code does not capture the file descriptor returned from `open()`, so the file is open but the code cannot use it because the file descriptor isn't know (it can't close it, for example). You'd normally find a notation such as `int fd; if ((fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDRW)) < 0) ...`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - the printf man page has %m as a glibc extension to print errno.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Duck; as I said, it isn't standard (as in, mandated by POSIX or ISO/IEC 9899), but it is helpful to know that it is a `printf()` conversion specifier on systems using glibc.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - First I learned of it.  Actually sort of a useful short cut.  I may make use of it.  ;)

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but allow me to say that opening `/dev/null` (other than `/dev/zero`, which makes sense) in read-write mode does not really make much sense, as it is permanently end-of-file. An exception would be when daemonizing a process, but otherwise I can't imagine an application.

Comment: Amusingly, POSIX **does** mandate a `%m` with these semantics for the `syslog` function, which otherwise matches the behavior of `printf`. So implementations that want `syslog` to be able to use the `printf`-family functions directly without pre-processing the format string to handle `%m` themselves in advance need to support this `%m` extension...

Comment: @Damon: I think permanent EOF is a much more commonly desirable behavior than an endless stream of zero bytes. Think about it: which do you see more in shell scripts? `</dev/zero` or `</dev/null`?

Comment: @R..: In a shell script, I agree -- but slightly different situation. Here, one makes the command more versatile, in accepting _some_ file, which may be "null file". In code like above, what would you want to do with a descriptor from which you already know at compile time that it will never succeed in reading? `/dev/null` only really makes sense as a sink here (say, for `stdout`), i.e. for writing. It's different with `/dev/zero` insofar as e.g. mapping it actually returns usable zero-pool memory, which makes sense. Not like opening something read-write means you _have to_ read, of course :-)

Comment: @Damon: Most obvious example is when you have a socket/pipe and want to close it so the other end sees it closed, but you also need the fd to still be valid because other parts of your code will still be waiting for events on it. You do something like `int new = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR); dup2(new, existing); close(new);`

Answer (score 2):

it opens a device known as /dev/null that discards anything written to it.  Basically a  waste basket.

So the code is opening that device in read/write mode.  If the open fails it calls a function `die` which prints the error literal you see along with the system error message returned from strerror(errno) and exits the program.  The literal you see passed to `die` is probably just a format string for `printf`.

> From man 3 [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):
>
> m (Glibc extension.)  Print output of strerror(errno).  No argument is required.

There doesn't seem to be a glibc function called `die()`; it is presumably a function defined by the author of the code snippet, and it presumably exits the function after reporting the error.  However, we can only make educated guesses.

Comment: The string for `die()` isnt' just a `printf()` format string because `%m` is not a valid conversion specifier in plain (standard — POSIX or ISO/IEC 9899) `printf()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - It appears to be a glibc extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `man 2 open` in a terminal window, or Google for it.

The [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function is used to open a file and assign a file descriptor. If `open()` fails, it returns a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

`open("filename", O_RDWR)` is equivalent to `fopen("filename", "w")`

[/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) - This is used to truncate any unwanted streams. Consider that you are running a command in terminal, which will print both `stdout` and `stderr` in the terminal. If you want to truncate errors, we can run the command like `cmd 2>/dev/null`. If you want to see only the compiler warnings during compilation, we can run like `make 1> /dev/null`.